# oracle sql column mapping with separate dictionary table in select

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a big select query with many joins. There is some relationship between main and dictionary tables based on user_id. I don't need to join dictionary table with the main query. Can we use CASE in this scenario? What are the other solutions for this? How can we use separate dictionary table to use its column user_name instead of user_id of main table in the select statement? I need to use user_name in the select statement, without adding it in the join statement, like below

main_table - user_id
dictionary - user_id, user_name

Example of what is required:

```
  select 
    mt.some_field,
    dictionary.user_name
    --(select user_name from dictionary d, main_table mt where d.user_id=mt.user_id --) user_name
..
..
    from main_table mt
    *
    *
    join tab1 t1 on t1.id1=mt.id1
    join tab2 t2 on t2.id2=mt.id2
    join tab3 t3 on t3.id3=mt.id3
    *
    group by mt.some_field,..,..
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use it. But there are some restrictions, the query should return only one value. If user_id is unique or primary key, then you can add this in select clause. It is called as scalar sub query.

```
select d.user_name from dictionary d where d.user_id = mt.user_id
```

There is no need to join again in scalar sub query.

Comment: user_id is a primary key, but using that expression as a subquery returns ORA-01427

Comment: Can you paste the query?

Comment: It happens only if dictionary have multiple records for same userid